# Dygraph graph gets distorted/partially shifted

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am regularly updating several Dygraphs graphs. After some period of time, normally a few minutes, some or all of them get corrupted as shown in the figure below. I haven't been able to tie this a particular event or browser. This happens even with a simple graph where I am just reloading the data stored in a CSV file. I call `updateOptions({ file: URL })` on the graph object, where `URL` points to the CSV file, followed by calling `resetZoom()` on the graph object to update the axes. Googling hasn't revealed anyone suffering similar behaviour, so I'm lost as to what is causing this.

[image: Corrupted Dygraphs graph - The grid lines are compressed over part of the graph and there is a discontinuity on the right.]

**Update 1:** It is linked to minimizing and maximizing the browser.

**Update 2:** The problem doesn't occur in Firefox. It does happen in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, although IE has the additional problem of freezing after a while (a problem for another day).

**Update 3:** Minimum working examples added at http://jsfiddle.net/williamshipman/tvxekq56/ and http://jsfiddle.net/williamshipman/af66qstt/. Repeatedly minimize and maximize the browser window, after a while the distortion occurs. The first example uses AngularJS (like my own work), while the second demonstrates the same bug in pure JavaScript. You may have to minimize and maximize more than a dozen times to see the bug, it seems pretty random.

Comment: Can you share a live repro? Ideally via dygraphs.com/fiddle or dygraphs.com/jsbin

Comment: I can't share my code, its commercial, but will look into making a MWE. I was hoping this is a known problem.

Comment: @danvk I've added two MWEs.

Answer (score 1):

For me similar problem appears when I show and hide Y2 axis.
This one line helped me: `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);`

File: `dygraph-canvas.js`

```
var DygraphCanvasRenderer = function(dygraph, element, elementContext, layout) {
  ...
  ctx = this.dygraph_.hidden_ctx_;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height); // <== clear whole canvas before cliping
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(this.area.x, this.area.y, this.area.w, this.area.h);
  ctx.clip();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried that fix with the latest Dygraph version, but it doesn't fix the problem. The area that is being drawn to shifts up and to the left, so I suspect that this change just clears the same shifted area.

Answer (score 1):

**The root of the problem**

Canvas context is not fully restored after all draw is done.

**Solution 1.** (workaround)

Injecting `canvas_ctx_.restore()` after draw is done and `context.save()` before. `save()` is needed because library is restoring the context before every draw(except the initial one).

```
let g = new Dygraph('graph', {
  underlayCallback: (context) => {
    context.save();
  },
  drawCallback: (dygraph) => {
    dygraph.canvas_ctx_.restore();
  },
});
```

**Solution 2.** (library fix)

Here is my commit you can apply to the lib's `src/dygraph.js` 
https://github.com/pawelzwronek/dygraphs/commit/c66ca37b82f14e096652a338cae8abf568b9c764